# Conflict in libraries dplyr::lag() and stats::lag()

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(stats)
```

I am running a lot of regressions with a lagged variable and my R console has a conflict with the above packages. I know that I can circumvent this problem by typing "dplyr::lag()" for every regression.

However, is there another solution to this?

Comment: Not really, this is one of the chief reasons (in my head) for the need for more-refined collision management in R. However, if you load `stats` before `dplyr`, you should always get `dplyr::lag`.

Comment: Use the conflicted package to make r prefer dplyr's lag function: https://conflicted.r-lib.org/

Comment: library(conflicted)
conflict_prefer("lag", "dplyr")

Comment: Or just type `lag <- dplyr::lag` at the top of your script so you have the correct `lag` function in your global workspace, which will always be the preferred version.

Answer (score 5):

Given that dplyr is at fault here for clobbering `lag` I would do it like this:

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
Lag <- dplyr::lag
```

Now you can use `lag` as usual and when you want to use dplyr's lag just use `Lag`.